# Approach for setting dynamic constructor parameter inside template class

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, initialization

Let's say we have a template class (I'll call it **TileCreator** ) based on another class **Tile**.
In some cases the constructor of the **Tile** class needs parameters for initialization.
Now the **TileCreator** class will construct many **Tile** Objects, so I would like to store the necessary parameters as a member variable in **TileCreator**.

Is there any good approach for this? How can I let my template code know, which types and how many those parameters are?

My only approach is to use a void* pointer that points on it, however, then I would need to manually allocate and free memory everytime?

Ideally it should work like this:

```
template<class Tile> class TileCreator {
public:
    void CreateNew() {
        Tile tile(par);
    }
    void setPar(void* par) {
        this->par = par;
    }
private:
    void* par;
};

class Cake {
public:
    Cake(int sugar, bool chocolate) {
        // ...
    }
};

int main() {
    TileCreator<Cake> baker;
    // baker.setPar(over 9000, true); obviously doesnt work like this
    return 0;
}
```

I would have to allocate a struct that contains all parameters and give its pointer and then also add constructor for every possible Tile to correctly read the struct and free it.

I hope there is a more elegant solution to this!

Comment: If the set of types supported by tile creator is known then you can use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Answer (score 0):

Edited my answer to the following:

This has the disadvantage, that you need one instantiated template object in `Creator` which will be used when creating other objects by calling the copy constructor. You would of course need to take care of managing the pointer (probably use a smart pointer)

```
template <typename Tile>
class Creator {
  private:
    Tile *tileTemplate;
  public:

    template <typename... Args>
    Creator(Args&& ... args) {
      tile = new Tile(std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
    }
    void createNew() {
      Tile tile = *tileTemplate;
    }
    ~Creator() {
      delete tileTemplate;   
    }
};

class A {
  public:
  A(int a, int b):a(a) {} 
};

class B {
  public:
  B(const std::string& a):a(a) {}
};

int main()
{

  Creator<A> ca(1,2);
  ca.createNew();

  Creator<B> cb("Hello");
  cb.createNew();

}
```

Comment: I think the idea is to save one set of parameters and use it several times. In your code you create `Tile` object immediately.

Comment: @Grandbrain Thanks, you are right. I adapted my answer accordingly

Comment: thanks! it actually works :D the idea to use a template is actually so simple, i dont even need to forwards the arguments in the Creator constructor since i need to change the parameters a few times, so i can just put a template with a setTemplate function...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to store the arguments and [`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) to invoke the `Tile` constructor with them.

```
template <typename T, typename... Tn>
class Factory
{
private:
    std::tuple<Tn...> args;

public:
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit Factory(Args&&... args)
    : args(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {
    }

    T operator()() const {
        return std::apply([](Tn const&... args)
        {
            return T(args...);
        }, args);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_factory(Args&&... args)
{
    return Factory<T, std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Used like so:

```
int main()
{
    auto const make_tile = make_factory<Tile>(1, 2.0f, true);
    make_tile();
    make_tile();
}
```

You could even replace the `Factory` class with a lambda and [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for an easier implementation.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_factory(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind([](auto&&... args)
    {
        return T(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

In C++20, you could use [`std::bind_front`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front), which would also allow you to pass additional arguments on creation.

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto make_factory(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::bind_front([](auto&&... args)
    {
        return T(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

```
int main()
{
    auto const make_tile = make_factory<Tile>(1, 2.0f);
    make_tile();
    make_tile(true);
    make_tile(false, "hello");
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks for that answer. I thought im already familiar with most of c++, but the variadic templates and parameter packs (all the stuff with "...") are actually very confusing right now, not sure where to start to fully understand whats going on, but i guess ill work my way through your code over the day. thanks!

Comment: so after trying to implement your first solution into mine, i still got an error C2664: 'std::tuple<>::tuple(const std::tuple<> &) noexcept': cannot convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to 'std::allocator_arg_t' - cant really get a clue what it means. after just copying your code into an emptry project i got the same error... i tried it with c++17 and c++20, both wont compile. the lambda solution i sadly cant use because my actual "Factory" is much bigger and more complex, actually its a container class that manages a std::map<int, std::map<int, T>> data type. maybe i forgot to #include something?

Comment: @Kaisky I'm afraid I don't have much idea what could be going on. Looks like it's not matching any `tuple` constructor. Perhaps the arguments you're passing are not compatible.